# Quartiles for only two data points

Tags: r

```
Name    Pay  Quartile
A       10     1
A       11     3
```

R code:
`MQuantile <-with(M,ave(M$pay,M$name,FUN = function(x)ntile(x,n=4)))`

I calculated `quartile` for the data points which have various count of distribution but one of my names has only two data points so when I calculate Quartile for this data it shows Quartile 1 and 3, why it's not shown as Quartile 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Because with only two data points, quartile is a silly thing to compute. Any answer it gave would be silly. It would be better if it refused to give any quartiles.

Answer (score 2):

Quartile 2 is the median, and is often not regarded as a 'quartile' in an analytical sense. I assume that's why it's not there. Q1 and Q3 are used in Statistics because they gives us the Interquartile Range, which can be quite useful.

Regardless, why are you using quartiles for 2 data points? Or even any statistical analysis whatsoever? There doesn't seem to be any value to obtain.